# 'Access Denied' in MySQL on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to use an ETL (in my current case, the free version of Talend). I've successfully set up a MySQL on Amazon RDS, logged in through the MySQL Workbench for Mac, and uploaded my company's Salesforce Tables into the database, using a text file to create the fields/tables.

That has all worked out well. I've actually been using CDIR security records every time I log in, using my current IP address. I know its not perfect, but its been working so far.

The trouble arises when I try to use an ETL to transfer data in the form of a 'job'. I get this error, no matter what I try to do:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3700
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tMysqlOutput_1
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '(Username)'@'c-(IPAddress).hsd1.pa.comcast.net' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4004)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2312)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
[statistics] disconnected
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at sqmigration.sfdcmigration_0_1.SFDCMigration.tSalesforceInput_1Process(SFDCMigration.java:2391)
    at sqmigration.sfdcmigration_0_1.SFDCMigration.runJobInTOS(SFDCMigration.java:4799)
    at sqmigration.sfdcmigration_0_1.SFDCMigration.main(SFDCMigration.java:4667)
Job SFDCMigration ended at 16:17 16/09/2012. [exit code=1]
```

Any Ideas what in the world is happening here? Is it because of my Users? I'm logging in as the master account, that I set through the AWS management portal. I tried creating new users using phpMyAdmin (running on my local machine, with MAMP, connected to the database), but I was getting errors there as well granting privs.

Sorry if this is remedial. Just trying to learn how this stuff works and help my company!

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: If you can connect to RDS, run this query : `SELECT CONCAT('''',user,'''@''',host,,'''') from mysql.user;`. Do you see ``username`@'%'` ?

Comment: Did you set up the DB Security Group when you created the MySQL RDS Instance ???

Comment: I updated the security group (simply the default) with my local machine's IP address. I think it is strange that I can be connected through the workbench/phpMyAdmin/etc, but Talend is then getting and authentication error. I'll try the code snippet you sent over ASAP.

Comment: I ran the script - I got all of the users, of which there is the master user, displayed as "username'@'%' , along wiht a few other usernames that I have tried to create, and rdsadmin. If my master user is displayed as '@'%', that means it can connect from any host, correct?

Comment: You should be able to. Please review the DB security group you defined the instance with. Check the CIDR within it.

Comment: If i understand CIDRs correctly, 0.0.0.0/0 is the most open, allowing any host to touch the server. Something more precise, such as 192.169.123.123/32 is more precise, and therefore more secure. I have edited the CIDR records to allow 0.0.0.0/0 for testing, but it still is giving me the error on the job. Is it something to do with the way my users are setup in the database, despite showing up as `username'@'%'` ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5948/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-cdd)

Comment: Rolando, or anyone else - any idea what this could be? Every bit of documentation I can find is a little trivial, and just assumes that this will work. Troubleshooting steps involve editing the security group, which I do not believe is the problem.

Comment: You can refer my existing answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17668235/787503